# How to read the contents of a file until match a regular expression?

Tags: node.js, file, stream, filesystems, chunks

I have a file with mixed content like

```
<file-metadata> ...JSON String... </file-metadata>
<raw-content> ...Big raw file content... </raw-content>
```

How can I do something in Node JS like this?

Read only the JSON string content inside "file-metadata" tag and ignore the rest of the Big raw file content using readable Stream.

Thanks for any help and sorry for any spelling mistakes.

Comment: read the file as a stream, and stop when it reads `</file-metadata>`